# How to define & init Matrix in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, matrix

I have a class which has two dimensional array as a private member - k rows and n columns (the size is not known when defining the Matrix).

I want init the Matrix using a special method: initMatrix, which will set the number of rows and cols in the matrix, and init all the data to 0.

I saw a way to init a multi-dimensional array in the following way:

```
  private var relationMatrix = Array.ofDim[Float](numOfRows,numOfCols)
```

but how can I define it without any size, and init it later?

Comment: If you're delaying initialization for efficiency reasons (e.g. might not always use it) then consider defining it as a `lazy val`. In Scala it's preferable to make your classes immutable, so late initialization of members is discouraged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you consider using an Option?

```
class MyClass() {
  private var relationMatrix: Option[Array[Array[Float]]] = None

  def initMatrix(numOfRows:Int, numOfCols:Int): Unit = {
    relationMatrix = Some(/* Your initialization code here */)
  }
}
```

The pros of this approach is that in any time you can know whether your matrix is initialized or not, by using `relationMatrix.isDefined`, or by doing pattern matching,

```
def matrixOperation: Float = relationMatrix match { 
  case Some(matrix) =>
    // Matrix is initialized
  case None =>
    0 // Matrix is not initialized
}
```

or map on it, like this:

```
def matrixOperation: Option[Float] = relationMatrix.map { 
  matrix: Array[Array[Float]] =>
  // Operation logic here, executes only if the matrix is initialized 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For declaring a mutable 2D array of floats without setting dimensions and values, consider

```
var a: Array[Array[Float]] = _
a: Array[Array[Float]] = null
```

For initialising it consider the use of `Array.tabulate` like this

```
def init (nRows: Int, nCols: Int) = Array.tabulate(nRows,nCols)( (x,y) => 0f )
```

Thus for instance,

```
a = init(2,3)
```

delivers

```
Array[Array[Float]] = Array(Array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), Array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

**Update** the use of `Option` (already suggested by @Radian) proves type-safe and more robust at run-time, in contrast with `null` initialisation; hence, consider also `Option(Array.tabulate)`.

Answer (score 1):

`var matrix: Array[Array[Float]] = null` — this declares a variable of the same type as yours

Comment: `null` is only in Scala for Java compatibility, and you shouldn't use it unless forced to by Java

Answer (score 1):

You can make your initMatrix method part of the companion object.

```
class Matrix(numOfRows:Int, numOfCols:Int) {
    private var relationMatrix = Array.ofDim[Float](numOfRows, numOfCols)
// your code there

}

object Matrix {
    def initMatrix(numOfRows:Int, numOfCols:Int) = Matrix(numOfRows, numOfCols)
}

var myMatrix = Matrix.initMatrix(3,5)
```